# Retrieve hyperparameters from a fitted xgboost model object

Tags: python, xgboost

Is there a way to retrieve from the fitted xgboost object the hyper-parameters used to train the model. More specifically, I would like to know the number of estimators (i.e. trees) used in the model. Since I am using early stopping, the n_estimator parameter would not give me the resulting number of estimators in the model.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the parameters of your model:
`print(model.get_xgb_params())`

Comment: Yes it gets me the number of trees I specified but it would not give me the actual number trees in the optimal model selected by early stopping

Comment: @PingPong are you using the early stopping in xgb.cv?

Answer (score 0):

model.get_params(deep=True) should show n_estimators

Then use model.get_xgb_params() for xgboost specific parameters.

Comment: For me, model.get_params(deep=True), model.get_params(deep=False) , model.get_xgb_params() all return exactly the same info.